# Tableau map filter

Tags: dictionary, filter, tableau-api

Has anyone encountered an issue like this before:

I've created a very basic map plotting 39 places in England using Longitude and Latitude points.

I have a table that accompanies the map, and when you select one of the 39 places on the map, I want this to update the table to show only values for this selection.

I've set up the map as a filter but for some reason, only 7 of the 39 work when selected.

I decided to extract the data and save the file as a packaged workbook, to send to a colleague to investigate. However, when I extract the data and save as a packaged workbook and open in Reader or Desktop, everything works as it should do. All 39 places on the map filter other sheets correctly.

So I guess my question is, why would my original desktop version not work, but by saving it/extracting the data, it works perfectly?

For additional information, I am connecting to a live SQL server data source.

Edit: Added screenshots. I don't have this problem when I extract data and save as a packaged workbook. All the filters work.

[image: Nothing filtered]

[image: Example filter not working]
[image: Example filter working]

Comment: That's a very generic question. Could you provide some more details around how the filters are set up? Ideally provide a screenshot of the full Tableau screen so that we can see if there are any other things that might look odd.

Comment: I have added screenshots. It is a generic question really but the screenshots should help. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved this one.

I was clicking on the actual map to 'Use as Filter'. What I have done instead is, go to Dashboard > Actions and Add Action making sure that the Target Filters are set to Selected Fields and not All Fields.

I think I'll avoid the 'Use as Filter' option from now on as that was a massive pain. It still makes no sense that it worked when extracted/saved as a packaged workbook, but then Tableau has lots of these little issues when you start using it more and more.